# Is there a power-management like OpenSuse?

Tags: laptop, power-management

In OpenSuse there is a applet for choosing different energy-profiles for your notebook. Are there any tools/applets that will enable those features for ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Battery Applet/Indicator**

This is designed as a replacement for the original battery indicator which will give you more information and options including 4 power levels

- Power Save
- Ondemand
- Normal
- Performance

It shows the charge level of your battery and whether you are using the battery or mains. It can be used as an indicator or a gnome applet so can be used on Ubuntu 11.04, 10.10 and older

To install you will need to add there ppa
 - `ppa:iaz/battery-status`
A guide for adding additional ppa sources is available here - 
[what is a ppa and how do I use them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) - after you have aded it an updated your system you can install `battery-status` from the Software Centre by searching for it.

Hope this helps

Comment: This sounds exactly for what I'm searching for. I remember, that the CPU-Load-indicator has nearly the same functionality. But I will give a try. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's power management utility has 2 different profiles (AC and battery) you can change these things from System -> Preferences -> Power Management . But as for a quick switcher nothing that I know of exists in official repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The below link provides details of installing Battery applet which also come with power profiles. check out

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/